# Baumgartner-Weiß-Schindler implementation

Tags: implementation

Is there any public implementation of the Baumgartner-Weiß-Schindler ([A Nonparametric Test for the General Two-Sample Problem](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2533862?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102328810767) test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/robertfeldt/FeldtLib.jl/blob/master/src/baumgartner_weis_schindler.jl) is one in Julia, with an MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

This test is implemented in the R package [`BWStest`](https://github.com/shabbychef/BWStest), which is available from CRAN via `install.packages('BWStest')`.